# Delete multiple columns with constraints from different tables 

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to delete different columns from different tables, using T-SQL.

I made this code, following some tips that I found here on SO

```
/* Declaration of variable */
declare @tablename nvarchar(200)
declare @colname nvarchar(200)
declare @default sysname, @sql nvarchar(max)

/* **** Modifications in TITULORECEBERFATURA_ITEMS**** */
/* Drop column NRSEQORDEM */
set @tablename = 'TITULORECEBERFATURA_ITEMS'
set @colname = 'NRSEQORDEM'

select @default = CONSTRAINT_NAME
FROM 
   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE 
WHERE 
   TABLE_NAME = @tablename 
   AND COLUMN_NAME = @colname

   set @sql = N'alter table ' + @tablename + ' drop constraint ' + @default
exec sp_executesql @sql

set @sql = N'alter table ' + @tablename + ' drop column ' + @colname
exec sp_executesql @sql
```

The above code works without any kind of problem. But when I add other code below it, occurs an error.

```
/* Declaration of variable */
declare @tablename nvarchar(200)
declare @colname nvarchar(200)
declare @default sysname, @sql nvarchar(max)

/* **** Modifications in TITULORECEBERFATURA_ITEMS**** */
/* Drop column NRSEQORDEM */
set @tablename = 'TITULORECEBERFATURA_ITEMS'
set @colname = 'NRSEQORDEM

select @default = CONSTRAINT_NAME
FROM 
   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE 
WHERE 
   TABLE_NAME = @tablename 
   AND COLUMN_NAME = @colname

   set @sql = N'alter table ' + @tablename + ' drop constraint ' + @default
exec sp_executesql @sql

set @sql = N'alter table ' + @tablename + ' drop column ' + @colname
exec sp_executesql @sql

/* **** Modifications in EMAILCONTAS **** */
/* Drop column NRSEQOPERADORA */
set @tablename = 'EMAILCONTAS'
set @colname = 'NRSEQOPERADORA'

select @default = CONSTRAINT_NAME
FROM 
   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE 
WHERE 
   TABLE_NAME = @tablename 
   AND COLUMN_NAME = @colname

   set @sql = N'alter table ' + @tablename + ' drop constraint ' + @default
exec sp_executesql @sql

set @sql = N'alter table ' + @tablename + ' drop column ' + @colname
exec sp_executesql @sql
```

The `NRSEQORDEM` and his constraint are dropped without problems, But I got this error with the `NRSEQOPERADORA` and his constraint column

> Msg 5074, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   The object 'FK_*EMAILCONT*_NRSEQ__25276EE5' is dependent on column 'NRSEQOPERADORA'.
>   Msg 4922, Level 16, State 9, Line 1
>   ALTER TABLE DROP COLUMN NRSEQOPERADORA failed because one or more objects access this column.

And the columns `NRSEQOPERADORA` doesn't drop.

If I use different names for **each** declare, I can do it (but there is not only 2, but lots of those, and is not pretty do it, I'm looking for a "right" way of doing this)

```
/* Declaration of variable */
    declare @tablename nvarchar(200)
    declare @colname nvarchar(200)
    declare @tablename2 nvarchar(200)
    declare @colname2 nvarchar(200)
    declare @default sysname, @sql nvarchar(max)

    /* **** Modifications in TITULORECEBERFATURA_ITEMS**** */
    /* Drop column NRSEQORDEM */
    set @tablename = 'TITULORECEBERFATURA_ITEMS'
    set @colname = 'NRSEQORDEM

    select @default = CONSTRAINT_NAME
    FROM 
       INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE 
    WHERE 
       TABLE_NAME = @tablename 
       AND COLUMN_NAME = @colname

       set @sql = N'alter table ' + @tablename + ' drop constraint ' + @default
    exec sp_executesql @sql

    set @sql = N'alter table ' + @tablename + ' drop column ' + @colname
    exec sp_executesql @sql

    /* **** Modifications in EMAILCONTAS **** */
    /* Drop column NRSEQOPERADORA */
    set @tablename2 = 'EMAILCONTAS'
    set @colname2 = 'NRSEQOPERADORA'

    select @default = CONSTRAINT_NAME
    FROM 
       INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE 
    WHERE 
       TABLE_NAME = @tablename2 
       AND COLUMN_NAME = @colname2

       set @sql = N'alter table ' + @tablename2 + ' drop constraint ' + @default
    exec sp_executesql @sql

    set @sql = N'alter table ' + @tablename2 + ' drop column ' + @colname2
    exec sp_executesql @sql
```

---

**EDIT:**

1. The code **works** The constraint is deleted, the column is deleted. (See first code sample)
2. If I put a follow script, with the **set** of a different table and column but using the same declare name (@tablename, @colname, @default), the first part of the code **will** drop the constrain and the column without any problem but the second script will show an error message (See the error quote and the second code sample)
3. I need to be able to make it more than once at the same time. I can't afford run one query at time, I'm doing a script to execute them all at once. But the Declare part is making things a little harder. If I use a different declare for every query, it's gonna work; But I don't think that this is the right way of doing this. This is why I'm wondering, how could I accomplish this? Or there is **no way** besides the workaround?

Comment: Notice that the code, first drop the constrain, then it drops the column. The problem is: The second code, can't access (or overwrite) the declare. And I can't use multiple declare with the same name. I could use different names for each declare, but I wanna do it in "the right way"

Answer (score 0):

Probably you first need to drop a constraint FK_*EMAILCONT*_NRSEQ__25276EE5
try

```
alter table ... drop constraint FK__EMAILCONT__NRSEQ__25276EE5
```

Comment: Yes, the first code, drop my constrain and then drop the column. My problem is when I try to use the second code. (using another table and another column) because they don't find the declare, or try to use it and can't. That is what idk, neither how can I fix this.